# How to restrict drag and drop for particular node in tree in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, treeview

I created treeview example in angularjs with drag and drop. I want to restrict drag and drop for particular node

Ex:-
node 1.2 always be child node need to restrict drop other node on node 1.2
and dynamically remove add button for node 1.2 or disable add button.

[Demo link(Plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/xTqHAPUSm5I20pHvmWMv?p=preview)

My Tree data :

```
$scope.data = [{
    'id': 1,
    'title': 'node1',
    'nodes': [
      {
        'id': 11,
        'title': 'node1.1',
        'nodes': [
          {
            'id': 111,
            'title': 'node1.1.1',
            'nodes': []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'id': 12,
        'title': 'node1.2',
        'nodes': []
      }
    ]
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'title': 'node2',
    'nodrop': true, // An arbitrary property to check in custom template for nodrop-enabled
    'nodes': [
      {
        'id': 21,
        'title': 'node2.1',
        'nodes': []
      },
      {
        'id': 22,
        'title': 'node2.2',
        'nodes': []
      }
    ]
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'title': 'node3',
    'nodes': [
      {
        'id': 31,
        'title': 'node3.1',
        'nodes': []
      }
    ]
  }];
}]);
```